# Why one should not do propensity model building for each imputation?

Tags: regression, modeling, missing-data, data-imputation, propensity-scores

Normally, multiple imputation goes as the following.

$Data\to Imputation\to Model\to Statistics$ and the statistics is pooled against a fixed model.

Q. For propensity score analysis, there is a stage of model building requiring propensity score model building. Is there any theoretical reason that I should fix a propensity score model? In other words, for different imputations, I could use different propensity score models to achieve better balance for individual imputation. However, it seems that overall statistics after imputation does not seem comparable at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "overall statistics after imputation does not seem comparable at all"? You get balance statistics from each imputation and effect estimates from each imputation, so what about them is not comparable?

Comment: @Noah For each imputation, there is a propensity score model built. The ATE is built upon estimated propensity score. In this case, ATE(whatever statistics) is dependent upon the choice of propensity score model as the matching depends upon propensity score model. I am wondering why I should not build a propensity score model for each ATE in the sense of selecting covariates. From imputation procedure, I should have fixed selection of covariates for propensity score model beforehand rather than during imputation.

Comment: Before starting your analysis, you need to decide which covariates you need to achieve balance on. How you achieve balance on them within imputations doesn't matter. It's better to use the same method across imputations, but the tuning parameters you use in each imputation can differ. Again, you get the same output from each imputation regardless of how the PS model is constructed, so you can easily combine the results across imputations.

Comment: @Noah I see. It does not matter even if tuned parameter/hyperparameters differ in each imputation.